MariaDB container fails to start due to volume issue with mysql.sock after switching from MySQL in Docker Compose
I'm currently switching from MySQL to MariaDB in my Docker-based development environment. After switching, my development-db-1 container is failing to start properly due to issues with the volume. I keep seeing the following error in the logs
chown: cannot dereference '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock': No such file or directory


Interestingly, my test_db container, which is also MariaDB, works fine because it uses a tmpfs volume instead of a bind mount for /var/lib/mysql. However, for the main db service, I need to persist the database, which requires using a bind mount for the volume.
What I have tried:
Updated the docker-compose.yaml to switch from mysql to mariadb:11.4.3.
Tried using the following command to change the ownership of the volume:
sudo chown -R 999:999 ./mysql-dev-volume


Recreated the volume by:
Stopping the containers: docker-compose down
Removing the volume: sudo rm -rf ./mysql-dev-volume
Recreating it: mkdir ./mysql-dev-volume && sudo chown -R 999:999 ./mysql-dev-volume
Tried starting the containers again: docker-compose up -d.
However, the error with mysql.sock still persists, and the container refuses to start. The relevant part of my docker-compose.yaml for db service looks like this:
services:
  db:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mariadb:11.4.3
    ports:
      - "33060:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: *****
      MYSQL_DATABASE: *****
      MYSQL_USER: *****
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: *****
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./mysql-dev-volume:/var/lib/mysql


Expected behavior: The MariaDB container should start and persist the database using the mysql-dev-volume. I expect the container to properly bind the volume and create the necessary mysql.sock file for connections.
Does anyone have any insight on why this volume issue might be happening with MariaDB, or how I can resolve the problem with mysql.sock? Thanks in advance!

Have you edited the configuration? I ask, because usually you find the socket file here: /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock

It is not recommended to use sock file for communicating between two containers. TCP communication is a lot more reliable for this setup.

Use named volume mounts over bind mounts. You could use --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mariadb.sock as a command:, but TCP connections are much more tested.
